# Buttons Transform Events

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a dilemma. I'm trying to do something like: I have 3 buttons, I click on one, it increases, I click on another one, it increases and the previous one returns to the original size.

```
    private void PigeonholesHasClicked(GameObject target, MouseEventType type)
{
    if (type == MouseEventType.CLICK)
    {
        TargetIndex = System.Array.IndexOf(Pigeonholes, target);
        PigeonholesTrasnform();
    }
}

Vector3 mPosition;
int lastIndex = 0;
public float mIndex;
private void PigeonholesTrasnform()
{
    mPosition = new Vector3(Pigeonholes[TargetIndex].transform.position.x - mIndex, Pigeonholes[TargetIndex].transform.position.y, 0f);
    Pigeonholes[TargetIndex].transform.DOMove(mPosition, 0.5f);
    Pigeonholes[TargetIndex].GetComponent<BoxCollider2D>().enabled = false;
    if (TargetIndex != lastIndex)
    {
        mPosition = new Vector3(Pigeonholes[lastIndex].transform.position.x + mIndex, Pigeonholes[lastIndex].transform.position.y, 0f);
        Pigeonholes[lastIndex].transform.DOMove(mPosition, 0.5f);
        for (int i = 0; i < Pigeonholes.Length; i++)
        {
            if (i != TargetIndex)
                Pigeonholes[i].GetComponent<BoxCollider2D>().enabled = true;
        }
    }
    lastIndex = TargetIndex;
}
```

The problem is that if I click on the 1 or 2 button, the 0 button moves to the right by 0.4.If I first start typing 0, then press 1 or 2, then everything goes ok.The idea is that the lastIndex is 0 initially, if I make it -1, it gives me an error. HELP!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you start you have nothing selected yet => you actually don't want it to be `0` initially.

I would leave `lastIndex = -1;` initially but simply ignore the lines

```c#
mPosition = new Vector3(Pigeonholes[lastIndex].transform.position.x + mIndex, Pigeonholes[lastIndex].transform.position.y, 0f);
Pigeonholes[lastIndex].transform.DOMove(mPosition, 0.5f);
```

if it is still `-1` -> meaning nothing was selected before:

```
if(lastIndex >= 0)
{
    mPosition = new Vector3(Pigeonholes[lastIndex].transform.position.x + mIndex, Pigeonholes[lastIndex].transform.position.y, 0f);
    Pigeonholes[lastIndex].transform.DOMove(mPosition, 0.5f);
}
```

Comment: Yes, that's what I did, and it's ok